# Exporting multiple constants as one json

Tags: javascript

I am having few constant files and an index.js file in a constant folder.

index.js file,

```
import  * as env from "./env.constants";
import  * as httpC from "./http.constants";
import  * as localStorage from "./localStorage.constants";
import  * as routes from "./routes.constants";

const appConstants =  {
  ...env,
  ...httpC,
  ...localStorage,
  ...routes
};

console.log(appConstants);

export default appConstants;
```

and my constant files are as follows ,

http.constants.js

```
export const GET = "GET";
export const POST = "POST";
```

Other files are having same exports with different names.
The console output of index.js is a json, containing all the constants.
[image]

But when I am importing them as

```
import * as test from "./constants";
  console.log(test);
```

I am getting the following output in my browser,
[image]

I want to use the constants in a single import,

```
import { GET, LOGIN_URL } from 'constants';
```

What have I missed ?

Comment: *"The console output of index.js is a json..."* No, it isn't. It's an *object*. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I am importing them as
>
> ```
> import * as test from "./constants";
>   console.log(test);
> ```
>
> I am getting the following output in my browser,

That's because you're importing the module's *module namespace object* (that's what `import *` does), and then outputting it directly.

To get the `constants` file you want, don't do the `import * as` and then combine them into an object and export that object as a default;instead, simply re-export them like this:

```
export * from "./env.constants";
export * from "./http.constants";
export * from "./localStorage.constants";
export * from "./routes.constants";
```

That will export all the named exports from all of those modules as named exports from the `constants` module.

---

What you were trying to do is a relatively common misunderstanding of the JavaScript module system, as compared to the CommonJS-like module system of Node.js. Named exports are **not** just properties on an object that's the default export. Named exports are their own first-level thing. If you do:

```
export default {
    foo: 42
};
```

...you can't do `import { foo } from "./mod"` to import it, because `foo` isn't a named export, it's just a property on the default export, which is an object.

---

> I am having few constant files and an index.js file in a constant folder.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> import { GET, LOGIN_URL } from 'constants';
> ```

FWIW, relying on that to import a `index.js` file from the `constants` folder is relying on Node.js-specific features, not anything built into the JavaScript module system. If you only expect it to work in Node.js, that's fine, but just beware that it's not standard.

Comment: Oh.. was not aware of this standard. This is a react project. So I should be storing the constants in json files, instead of js file ?

Comment: @BhaskerYadav - No, I'm not really seeing how you get that from the answer above. (And again: There's no JSON anywhere in your question or the answer.) Defining constants in JavaScript files is fine. This is how you roll up multiple modules that are doing that into a single module.